# How can I use the value of a variable and check if a variable with the name of that value exists in batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to check if the value of a variable exists as a variable
Example:

```
Set /p i=input:                                 
if %i%=="" echo not exist                             
echo exist
```

The problem is it checks if i exists and not if the value of I
exists as a variable. I need to check if what the user inputs exists as a variable.

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understood you, you want to read *the name* of a variable and check if such variable exists, that is:

```
set myVar=any value

Set /p i=input:
if defined %i% echo The variable %i% exist
```

In the previous example, if you enter "myVar" (without quotes), the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

The better ant robust  approach is to use `if defined` - it checks if variable is defined

```
if defined i echo i is defined
```

To check if value is empty you can use:

```
if "%i%"== "" echo i is not defined
```

Comment: Code snippets on their own are not very informative. Please explain what the code does, why you wrote it that way, and how you expect it to work